# Determining if two words are anagrams

Tags: javascript, strings

I was given a this problem at a technical interview and failed miserably in the time given. Afterwards, I sat down and worked out what I think is a good solution. The task was actually to build an AngularJS app to do this, which I did, but the guts of my solution is in JavaScript. I wanted to ask if there is a better way to do this:

```
// convert strings to LC for case insensitivity
// split strings into arrays
// sort the arrays (spaces will sort first and be trimmed later)
// join the arrays back into strings
// we're only concerned about the printable characters in the anagram so,
// trim() to remove any spaces and then compare the resulting strings
var str1 = this.word1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();
var str2 = this.word2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();

if (str1 === str2) {
    this.isAnagram = true;
} else {
    this.isAnagram = false;
}
```

Comment: As it often happens, the best solution depends heavily on your constraints, which aren't clear at all. Can you assume that both word1 and word2 are actually strings? Can you assume that they only contain letters? Do you need type conversion? Do you need to treat "ÿ" like "y"? Do you need error handling? Etc...

Comment: If you're writing real code on a team for a real project, your solution above is perfect.  ie, the only concern in software, for 20 years, is readability and clarity --so, you get an A.  (In the extremely unusual case that **performance** is relevant, there are great explorations of that concept below, which you can take as an interesting, sort of historic footnote to the issue. Note though that, of course, **if you present a "performance" solution that's a total fail**: you're job, your existence, your life, your every heartbeat is one simple concept: readability.)

Comment: Regarding this now extremely confusing QA.  I feel it is well worth restating that (1) **matching an anagram (sort, equality) is an utterly, utterly, utterly trivial process**  (2) of course, obviously, you do it in a line of code using the utterly trivial .Net calls available to you for the purpose. It is, simply, utterly inconceivable you would start "writing code!" to do that. **No more than you would start "writing code!" to, for example, divide two numbers or to make a string lowercase.**

Comment: I'm sorry to use the word "utterly" so often but it's that type of QA!  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if two strings are anagrams](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69883/check-if-two-strings-are-anagrams)

Comment: And just note too that this trivial question is a many-times duplicate on this site

Answer (score 28):

My original assertion (Outdated):

> Sorting a string (Or any array) is inefficient because even the
>   fastest algorithm will sort no faster than O(n log n) in an average
>   case. The most efficient way would use a hash map to count letters in
>   each word. Something like:

Although reading from a hash map can be as quick as O(1), writing to a hash map is significantly slower. By using a 26-value array (0-25) to represent lowercase letters, the speed of operations can be sped up significantly:

```
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
  if (typeof word1 !== 'string' || typeof word2 !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('isAnagram requires two strings to be passed.')
  }

  var normalizedWord1 = word1.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  var normalizedWord2 = word2.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, '').toLowerCase();

  var counts = [];
  var word1Length = normalizedWord1.length;
  var word2Length = normalizedWord2.length

  if (word1Length !== word2Length) { return false; }

  for (var i = 0; i < word1Length; i++) {
    var index = normalizedWord1.charCodeAt(i)-97;
    counts[index] = (counts[index] || 0) + 1;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < word2Length; i++) {
    var index = normalizedWord2.charCodeAt(i)-97;
    if (!counts[index]) { return false; }
    else { counts[index]--; }
  }

  return true;
}
```

EDIT: A speed comparison between using a hash and using a 26-value array:
http://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms

Comment: Yes. 3n is an order of magnitude faster than n log n.

Comment: @Tushar If you're interested in learning a little about computational complexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: I don't get it. The OP and @Tushar solution only check if the word is a palindrome, am I wrong? I so, this is the only correct solution by now, because checks anagrams.

Comment: @ItaloAyres Both other solutions are sorting the letters of the word alphabetically and comparing. That will check for anagrams. The difference  between our approaches is the computational complexity of the algorithms.

Comment: @rrowland I just mentally jumped the use of sort() method. Thanks! And about the "which is the fastest" discussion, I prefer solving it the easy way: testing it! haha.

Comment: @ItaloAyres See [Anagram Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram). Notice `William Shakespeare = I am a weakish speller`. This answer will state that these are not Anagrams

Comment: @rrowland You can remove `trim()` from `word1.trim().replace(/ /g, '');` As `replace`  is removing spaces. Also, use `\s+` instead of space ` ` in `regex`

Comment: @rrowland Also remove `!word1 || !word2 || `. Will not work if I passed `0` as one of the string

Comment: @Tushar +1 on removing trim and using \s. `0` is not a string. `"0"` is truthy.

Comment: @rrowland Anyway `!word1 || !word2 || !word1.length || !word2.length` is redundant. You can remove one of them.

Comment: @EasyBB Yeah I wasn't aware for..in was that much slower. A quick Google search enlightened me. Thanks!

Comment: You should consider using `every` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: -1 Because a HashMap is typically implemented as a Heap, which is O(log n) for inserting. More to the point. You are in effect doing the equivilent of an Insert Sort on a Heap, which "dun dun dun" is O(n log n).

Comment: @Aron: Where did you get that from? A [*Hash*Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is implemented using hashing, with amortised `O(1)` access. No heapsort going on.

Comment: This function is broken. `isAnagram('abccd', 'abcdd')` gives back `true`. You need to make sure the count of each letter is the same in both hashes, not just that they have the same set of distinct letters.

Comment: @Bergi Where are the buckets stored?

Comment: @Aron: Some indexed constant access structue, call it array of buffer or whatever.

Comment: @Bergi The buckets are typically stored in a Heap. You could create an implementation based on an constant sized array (which would need to be the size of 2^(size of the hash). But that is typically quite memory inefficient. In this case, we KNOW that there are only 26 different chars (excluding accents (yes english HAS accents you naïve fool)) and you can base an algorithm on an array sized 26, but it wouldn't be a generic HashMap. In fact it would not be a HashMap, since the identity function can hardly be called a Hash function.

Comment: @jpmc26 has a point here. You forgot to initialise your properties, and they all are becoming `NaN` (which is falsy in the end, you might better have used an explicit `== 0`).

Comment: @Aron: I think you're confusing [a heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) with [the heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(programming)). Yes, initialising the map with the 26 expected letters might improve the performance, but that's really not needed as JS objects dynamically resize their maps.

Comment: @Bergi no I am not. At the size we are working in, it is n log n. The log n part however is bounded...

Comment: @Bergi Whoops. I misdiagnosed the cause. Thanks. =)

Comment: @Aron: What do you mean by "*at the size we are working in*"? If we put a bound on input size (word length), we get `O(1)`, and if we put a bound on the number of characters we get `O(n)` (linear to input size).

Comment: @jpmc26 You're right, it was broken. But, the problem was I forgot to initialize the letters in the hash as Numbers. So I was trying to ++ on undefined and they all became NaN which made them equal. The updated code is working again.

Comment: @Bergi As you fill in the Bucket Heap, it tends to an array.

Comment: @Aron You made a good point about insertion speed. I sped up the algorithm by converting the lowercase characters to values 0-25 so they can quickly be looked up in by array index rather than by hash key.

Comment: Check out the speed delta! http://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms

Comment: `if (!word1 || !word2 || !word1.length || !word2.length)` will fail if I pass an array or an array-like object.

Comment: You may be able to return false from that second loop a bit earlier (before attempting to subtract) if `!counts[index]`.

Comment: @JcT Great observation! I've added a conditional.

Comment: I think [my solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/99289/36863) might be a little bit [faster](https://jsperf.com/simontheflutists-anagram-algorithms).

Comment: @Aron, HashMap aren't implemented using heaps, you have no idea what you are talking about. See for example the wikipedia article which describes the array of buckets, and never mentions heaps. The fact is, using a heap to implement a hash map is utterly nonsensical.

Comment: Just a thought - now that the conditional is in there, you may not even need that last `.every` loop. Anything I'm missing in thinking you can just return true?

Comment: @JcT The `.every` loop is still catching instances where the first word has more of a certain letter than the second. The conditional is only catching instances where the second word has more of a certain letter than the first.

Comment: Ah, but we know they're both the same length - so we'll either have exactly the same letters in the second string, or we'll have a letter in it that we don't have in the first. The first word having more of something means it will also have less of something else, since both words have the same available space. So say we had `abb` and `abc` (where the first has more 'b's than the first); in the second loop, we'll fail when we try to subtract from `c`, yes? If we survive the second loop, it means we had the same lengths and the second word didn't have any chars that weren't in the first.

Comment: One other consideration - the regex we're using to strip spaces doesn't necessarily guarantee we only have alphas left; but our expectation of having a 26-value array assumes we are; I'd think there'd be some potential issues there.

Comment: Any thoughts as to whether you could also get away with `typeof word1 !== "string" || typeof word2 !== "string"` in the guard at the top of the function? Guarantees we're not receiving an Array; one empty string will fail the length check, two will pass on through as anagrams. I suppose "" is in fact an anagram of ""!

Comment: All good points @JcT, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Glad to help! Regarding performance, this code now performs pretty well against the prime hashing technique when you test against values that _aren't_ anagrams; which, to be fair, most aren't. There is a potential speed improvement if you set `counts` to an array with 26 zeros (you can remove the `||` in the first loop, and I think some engines can optimise better knowing the length and type in the array), but it does make the code a little less pretty: http://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms/7

Answer (score 24):

Everybody is talking about your algorithm, but everybody does the same mistake.

Repeated code! Yeah, you have repeated code.

Look at the following lines:

```
var str1 = this.word1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();
var str2 = this.word2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();
```

Just look how long that is! And repeated! Move that to a new function:

```
var regularize = function(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();
}
```

And now you can do like this:

```
var str1 = regularize(this.word1);
var str2 = regularize(this.word2);
```

But you have this a few lines below:

```
if (str1 === str2) {
    this.isAnagram = true;
} else {
    this.isAnagram = false;
}
```

So, you don't need those variables or anything... Cleaning up, you can just do:

```
this.isAnagram = regularize(this.word1) == regularize(this.word2);
```

---

As suggested many times before, you can do some cleanup to the string. Regular expressions come to my mind. Based on [@Tushar's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/99248/53773), I came up with this:

```
var regularize = function(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z\d]/g,'').split('').sort().join('');
}
```

---

All assembled together:

```
var regularize = function(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z\d]/g,'').split('').sort().join('');
}
this.isAnagram = regularize(this.word1) == regularize(this.word2);
```

Pretty short, isn't it?

Comment: Please, have the kindness to explain the downvotes

Comment: While I like that someone is focusing on readability, I don't think that moving that section of doubled code into a separate function enhances readability - rather, it makes it necessary to refer elsewhere to see what the code does.  When the code is simply duplicated on successive lines, it's very obvious that the code is the same.  (The downvote wasn't from me, though.)

Comment: @Brilliand The idea was to improve readability to making the code DRY and reducing other bloat. The same idiomatic meaning is still present on both ways. Mine simply removed all bloat. I believe it is easier to read this than the original. Yes, you have to refer to somewhere else, but if something is repeated then maybe it's time to have it's own function.

Comment: Moving the duplicated code into its own function is a prerequisite to improving its implementation (for example, we could populate a histogram instead).  If, after refactoring the function, you think it's worth inlining again, that's a decision to make at that point.  So I'm all for extracting repeated functionality like this - it's very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Your solution is not removing **punctuations and spaces** before checking if two strings are **Anagrams**.

Also, the code can be optimized.

1. First, *remove all the spaces and punctuation marks* from both the strings using *Regular Expression*
2. Check if the *`length` of strings are equal*, if not return `false` immedietly
3. Check for *Anagrams* only when both strings are of equal length.

Code:

```
var regex = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;

var str1 = this.word1.replace(regex, ''),
    str2 = this.word2.replace(regex, '');

this.isAnagram = str1.length > 0 && str1.length === str2.length && (str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('') === str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''));
```

This will first check for the `length` of strings are equal, if equal then only `(str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('') === str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''))` is evaluated.

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiter of `regex`
2. `[]`: Character class
3. `[^..]`: **Not** containing any of the following characters
4. `a-z0-9`: All alphanumeric characters
5. `g`: Global flag. Matches all the characters from the class
6. `i`: Case insensitive match

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1pubodrc/)

```js
var regex = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var str1 = (document.getElementById('str1').value).replace(regex, ''),
    str2 = (document.getElementById('str2').value).replace(regex, '');

  var isAnagram = str1.length > 0 && str1.length === str2.length && (str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('') === str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''));

  alert('Is Anagram: ' + isAnagram);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="str1" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="str2" />
<br />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="check" />
```

**Edit**

Another approach:

```
var checkAnagram = (function () {
    var sanitizeRegex = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;

    var sanitizeString = function (str) {
        return str.replace(sanitizeRegex, '').toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');
    };

    return function (str1, str2) {
        return sanitizeString(str1) === sanitizeString(str2);
    };
}());

var isAnagram = checkAnagram('Rust! Ha?', 'Tushar'); // Usage
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xxxk6kmz/)

Comment: Would "Rust Ha" be considered an anagram of "Tushar"? if so then this approach wouldn't quick cover all cases.

Comment: Only that one of the side effects of `.toLowerCase().split('').sort()` would be to sort all of the spaces to the end (or beginning, I haven't tested which), but this would fail the length test (despite trimming) (took me a while to come up with a clever anagram to illustrate this point, please don't take any offense :)

Comment: @JasonSperske Got it. Thanks. I've updated answer

Comment: If I was interviewing someone and looking for how complete they attempted to solve a programming puzzle I would consider this a strong answer. `Rust? Ha!` `Tushar` :)

Comment: Downvoter, Please comment here, why downvoted? Can something be improved?

Comment: An opposition to regex?

Comment: @JasonSperske `regex` has to be used. There is no other way.

Comment: It was just a guess, I've found blanket opposition to regex in the past, your approach has my upvote

Comment: Except for the fact his method is the slowest method of the three contending functions

Comment: Tushar, "trim" removes spaces.

Comment: @JoeBlow I know. What about `trim` in this context?

Comment: Hi Tushar - sorry don't follow you.  Here's the spec https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Far more importantly, see my comments BELOW THE MAIN QUESTION, which absolutely override all other considerations.  Note too that (if for some astounding reason you were writing 'performance' code for this - **note, it's almost impossible to even create a theoretical situation where that would be the case - I can't make one up**) .. everything presented here is pretty much a non-starter.  Performance code can only start with a context, for example, typically you'd be sorting against a **set of** (perhaps a dictionary) of words, not just one, or they might be arriving from the net, or...

Comment: ..whatever.  It's also well worth reiterating that the idea of "performance code" with a high level language is ... nutty. At best this is an abstract discussion of "pseudo performance code". Note too that (no offence meant at all)) the "performance concepts" discussed here are totally naive.  But in any event, as I say the **overwhelming reality** for this actual question is that, if you have any sort of job or work on a team, the only solution is, in fact, the line of code presented in the original OP! **engineering today is about simplicity and readability, nothing else whatsoever.**...

Comment: again the idea that for something as **utterly trivial** as "match anagram", you'd do anything other than the totally, utterly, obvious line of .Net code you use to do that ................. is really just pretty "fully silly" you know?!  Just to endlessly repeat, anyone who say had a job, and started to **write code** for such an incredibly trivial task - would be fired on the spot.  I mean you might as well start hand-writing code for other utterly trivial tasks like comparing two strings or the like.

Answer (score 4):

I have some boilerplate code similar to rrowland's, but I feel like my algorithm could be a little bit faster. It operates in O(n) by using prime number multiplication to count letters, and is non-branching in the longest-time routine.

Instead of doing `ind - 97` I keep 97 empty spots in the array that is accessed.

I think if you were more obsessive you could do the counting using bitwise operations, but this is good enough.

```
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
  if (!word1 || !word2 || !word1.length || !word2.length) {
    throw new Error('isAnagram requires two strings to be passed.')
  }

  var nword1 = word1.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  var nword2 = word2.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

  var length1 = nword1.length;
  var length2 = nword2.length;

  if (length1 !== length2) {
    return false;
  }

  var word1hash = 1;
  var word2hash = 1;

  var primes = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101];

  var ind;
  for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    ind = nword1.charCodeAt(i);
    word1hash *= primes[ind];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    ind = nword2.charCodeAt(i);
    word2hash *= primes[ind];
  }

  console.log(word1hash);
  console.log(word2hash);

  return word1hash == word2hash;
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

I guess we have a speed contest now, and this version is a great deal faster than all its precedents ([benchmark](https://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms/5)).

```
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
  if (!word1 || !word2 || !word1.length || !word2.length) {
    throw new Error('isAnagram requires two strings to be passed.')
  }

  var nword1 = word1;
  var nword2 = word2;

  var length1 = nword1.length;
  var length2 = nword2.length;

  if (length1 !== length2) {
    return false;
  }

  var word1hash = 1;
  var word2hash = 1;

  var tab = {'q': 2, 'w': 3, 'e': 5, 'r': 7, 't': 11, 'y': 13, 'u': 17, 'i': 19, 'o': 23, 'p': 29, 'a': 31, 's': 37, 'd': 41, 'f': 43, 'g': 47, 'h': 53, 'j': 59, 'k': 61, 'l': 67, 'z': 71, 'x': 73, 'c': 79, 'v': 83, 'b': 89, 'n': 97, 'm': 101, 'Q': 2, 'W': 3, 'E': 5, 'R': 7, 'T': 11, 'Y': 13, 'U': 17, 'I': 19, 'O': 23, 'P': 29, 'A': 31, 'S': 37, 'D': 41, 'F': 43, 'G': 47, 'H': 53, 'J': 59, 'K': 61, 'L': 67, 'Z': 71, 'X': 73, 'C': 79, 'V': 83, 'B': 89, 'N': 97, 'M': 101, ' ': 1}

  for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    word1hash *= tab[word1[i]]
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    word2hash *= tab[word2[i]]
  }

  return word1hash == word2hash;
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

I know this is silly, but adding logarithms of prime numbers is actually a tiny bit faster. ([benchmark](https://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms/5))

```
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
  if (!word1 || !word2 || !word1.length || !word2.length) {
    throw new Error('isAnagram requires two strings to be passed.')
  }

  var length1 = word1.length;
  var length2 = word2.length;

  var word1hash = 1;
  var word2hash = 1;

  var tab = {'q': 0.6931471805599453, 'w': 1.0986122886681098, 'e': 1.6094379124341003, 'r': 1.9459101490553132, 't': 2.3978952727983707, 'y': 2.5649493574615367, 'u': 2.833213344056216, 'i': 2.9444389791664403, 'o': 3.1354942159291497, 'p': 3.367295829986474, 'a': 3.4339872044851463, 's': 3.6109179126442243, 'd': 3.713572066704308, 'f': 3.7612001156935624, 'g': 3.8501476017100584, 'h': 3.970291913552122, 'j': 4.07753744390572, 'k': 4.110873864173311, 'l': 4.204692619390966, 'z': 4.2626798770413155, 'x': 4.290459441148391, 'c': 4.3694478524670215, 'v': 4.418840607796598, 'b': 4.48863636973214, 'n': 4.574710978503383, 'm': 4.61512051684126, 'Q': 0.6931471805599453, 'W': 1.0986122886681098, 'E': 1.6094379124341003, 'R': 1.9459101490553132, 'T': 2.3978952727983707, 'Y': 2.5649493574615367, 'U': 2.833213344056216, 'I': 2.9444389791664403, 'O': 3.1354942159291497, 'P': 3.367295829986474, 'A': 3.4339872044851463, 'S': 3.6109179126442243, 'D': 3.713572066704308, 'F': 3.7612001156935624, 'G': 3.8501476017100584, 'H': 3.970291913552122, 'J': 4.07753744390572, 'K': 4.110873864173311, 'L': 4.204692619390966, 'Z': 4.2626798770413155, 'X': 4.290459441148391, 'C': 4.3694478524670215, 'V': 4.418840607796598, 'B': 4.48863636973214, 'N': 4.574710978503383, 'M': 4.61512051684126, ' ': 0.0
}

  for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    word1hash += tab[word1[i]]
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
    word2hash += tab[word2[i]]
  }

  return word1hash == word2hash;
}
```

**Edit 3: removed equal length check.**

Comment: +1 The prime multiplication makes it faster. I'd probably find a way to turn your literal construction of 97 consecutive zeroes into something more readable and maintainable, though.

Comment: @rrowland, I'm actually not exactly sure as to whether the literal 97 zeros are faster than subtracting 97 from the index. It was just a conjecture. The funny thing was, on jsperf when I declared `primes` in the initializer's scope, the whole function was way slower—go figure.

Comment: I ran a benchmark - rrowland's answer runs in about half the time the OP does, and this runs in about half the time of rrowland's answer.  (Warning to anyone else benchmarking or using this: take out the `console.log`s before running this ten thousand times.)

Comment: Here's a comparison on jsperf: http://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms/3

Comment: I suspect there will be some cases of long words that this function counts as anagrams when they really aren't, though - javascript integers start losing precision after a certain point, and this function will tend to cross that threshold after ten letters or so.

Comment: @Brilliand, that's true. I considered redoing this with FP and logarithms, which might be faster since addition is a little faster than multiplication.

Comment: I updated my answer to eliminate the regex. It is about 40,000 times faster than OP.

Comment: Note than version 2 may fail on equal length test of 'words' with different number of spaces in them. Whether or not that matters...

Comment: @JcT Why? ' ' becomes 0.

Comment: Test for equal length happens before conversion of spaces. 'a b c' vs 'a bc' would fail before hashing since lengths are 5 vs 4, yes? But guess it comes down to whether you consider different numbers of spaces to be allowed, of course.

Comment: @JcT You're right; that's a vestige in fact of rrowland's code. I'll fix it.

Comment: I think it may have had a slight impact on some of the earlier performance results (algorithms that failed early appeared to have run quickly). I've slapped together a perf test revision that hopefully confirms consistent behaviour between algorithms, although I may be missing a few of yours. Interesting to see some significant differences in browsers handling the primes in a hashmap, though...: http://jsperf.com/anagram-algorithms/7

Comment: Hmm, running the logarithmic solution `isAnagram('racecar', 'racerac') ==
false`

Comment: @rrowland Well, I honestly expected small FP problems with the log solution. Discount it, then.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easy example

```
function isAnagram(strFirst, strSecond) {

 if(strFirst.length != strSecond.length)
       return false;

 var tempString1 = strFirst.toLowerCase();
 var tempString2 = strSecond.toLowerCase();

 var matched = true ;
 var cnt = 0;
 while(tempString1.length){
    if(tempString2.length < 1)
        break;
    if(tempString2.indexOf(tempString1[cnt]) > -1 )
        tempString2 = tempString2.replace(tempString1[cnt],'');
    else
        return false;

    cnt++;
 }

 return matched ;

 }
```

Calling function will be `isAnagram("Army",Mary);`
Function will return `true` or `false`

Comment: It would help if you explained why this code is better than what the OP and other people posted and how it is different from the other answers.